# Connect to MongoDB inside a Docker container with NodeJS don't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, connection

The host inside the container is ip:27017 and I can successfully connect from MongoDB Compass but not with my containerized NodeJS app.

How can I connect a NodeJS app in Docker to another container with MongoDB ?

Here the error I get :

```
Error :Error occurred connecting to MongoDB... MongoDB

-- disconnect --

Error: Failed to connect to mongo

    at MongoDB.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/dist/db/mongo.js:45:27)

    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)

    at fulfilled (/usr/src/app/dist/db/mongo.js:5:58)

    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Please share configuration how you've started those containers. 
Did you used docker-compose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

First, I changed ip address by the name of the mongodb container in env variables of my project.

Then, instead of launching container directly from Docker Desktop I used this command :

```
docker run -d -p 3001:3001 --name MyApp --link mongodb-container:mongodb-container MyApp
```

But this is only a workaround due to the deprecation of --link tag :
[Docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/)